# Burninate the [dell] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [dell](/questions/tagged/dell) tag does not add any useful information to questions other than "I am using something made by Dell". The range of questions includes [laptops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315441/cant-install-webcam-driver-for-dell-latitude-3440), [monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315441/cant-install-webcam-driver-for-dell-latitude-3440), [android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313396/dell-streak-setting-it-up-to-use-in-eclipse) and [tape drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399589/programming-dell-tape-drive-with-c-sharp) so the tag does not really add any value.

I think a bunch of questions in this tag need to be closed and then it should be burninated for the same reasons as the [microsoft and apple tags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199189/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)

Comment: You can do it yourself, or at least start the process yourself; just remove the tag from each of the 50 questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about burninating a tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @slugster there is already a Close reason "This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network", no need for custom reason.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know... I voted to close two questions this way as an experiment to see if it was useful to mention Meta.SO specifically.

Comment: @slugster I see. Well, no harm but also don't think it's needed as it's quite clear where the question belongs. That said, think those better be migrated to MSO, but not my decision to make.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a dramatization of what happened to the dell tag:

[image]